# How do I refresh a remote picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a picture in a DIV on site abc.com which is hosted elsewhere, for example `<IMG SRC="http://xyz.com/image.jpg">`.

It loads fine, but, I need to update this every few seconds.

The majority of items to upload are local, but the following code will not work for remote pictures:

`$('#rightpic').load('http://xyz.com/image.jpg', null);`

By trying this, I am getting an error : `...is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Can anyone recommend a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have control over the remote server (i.e. xyz.com)?

Comment: dont use the load method, instead try changing the img control src attribute, it shall work.

Comment: What is `rightpic`? The `img`? The `div`?

Comment: @jrrdnx - yes and no! It is our server, but, it is running Cacti and I  wouldn't really feel comfortable changing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out, you want to actually change the src, not use the .load() function.

```
$('#rightpic').get(0).src = 'http://xyz.com/image.jpg';
```

Comment: `get` is only needed for negative indexes. Usually you want `[]`, e.g., `$("#rightpic")[0].src = ...`

Answer (score 1):

`.load` uses an AJAX request, thus the same origin policy applies - which restricts cross-domain requests. Besides, it's not the best way to load images anyway. Also, setting the same url as `src` will often load images from the cache.

Instead, you should add a random query string value every request, like a timestamp, to ["bust the cache"](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/)

```
var img = document.getElementById('rightpic');

//update every 10 seconds using time from epoch as random value
setInterval(function(){
    var randomValue = new Date().getTime();
    img.src = "http://example.com/image.jpg?t="+randomvalue;
},10000);
```